# Studying the convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Good day. I can't find out what is the convergence of this series. I think that we must use the D'Alembert rule, but the simplification of the limit is giving me some problems.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{n^{2n}+2^n}$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The series converges. Note

$$0 < \frac{(2n)!}{n^{2n} + 2^n} < \frac{(2n)!}{n^{2n}}$$

and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{n^{2n}}$ converges by the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)^{2n+2}}}{\frac{(2n)!}{n^{2n}}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n} = \frac{4}{e^2} < 1.$$

Hence, by the comparison test, $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{n^{2n} + 2^n}$ converges.